# How to generate dropdownlist items based on another dropdown item selection in javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I found similar questions here but those were server side code, whereas I wanted to do it using javascript & jquery. Below are the codes..

**C# code to return data in JSON format**

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeesByDepartment(int departmentId)
{
  var employees = new EmployeeInfoRepository().GetEmployeesByDepartmentId(departmentId);
  var employeeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

  foreach (var emp in employees)
  {
    if(!employeeDictionary.ContainsKey(emp.EmployeeID))
    {
      employeeDictionary.Add(emp.EmployeeID, emp.FullName);
    }
  }

  return Json(employeeDictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

**Javascript code for Binding Data into DropDownList**

```
$("#ddlDepartment").change(function () {
  var id = $("#ddlDepartment option:selected").val();
  GetEmployeeByDepartmentId(id);
});

function GetEmployeeByDepartmentId(id) {
  var postData = {
    departmentId: id
  };

  $.ajax('/Leave/GetEmployeesByDepartment', {
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: postData,
    async: false,

    success: function (response) {

      $.each(response, function() {
        $("#ddlEmployee").append(
          $('<option/>', {
            value: this,
            html: this
          })
        );
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I also tried below inside the "Success" function, but this too doesn't work.

```
if (response == false) {
  alert("No Employee found for this department");
} else {
  $("#ddlEmployee").html = "";
  response.each(function(index, item) {
    $("#ddlEmployee").append("<option value='item.Key'>item.Value </option>");
  });
}
```

**EDITED code as suggested**

**C# code to return data in JSON format**

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeesByDepartment(int departmentId)
{
  var employees = new EmployeeInfoRepository().GetEmployeesByDepartmentId(departmentId);
  return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

**Javascript code (Success function only)**

```
if (response == null) {
  alert("No Employee found for this department");
} else {
    $.each(response, function () {
       var option = $('<option></option>');
         option.val(response.EmployeeID);
         option.text(response.FullName);
         $("#ddlEmployee").append(option);
    });
}
```

"Success" function is called and an array of object is returned. However, the data is still not binding into "ddlEmployee".

**Final Solution**
Currently doing this using below code-

```
$("#ddlEmployee").empty();
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
  $("#ddlEmployee").append('<option value=' + value.EmployeeID + '>' + value.FullName + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that success is called and jquery finds #ddlEmployee ?

Comment: Why are you returning a `Dictionary`?

Comment: try this $("#ddlEmployee").append(new Option(item.Key, item.Value));

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I do not understand how would I bind data from returned object array, that's why trying to simplify with a Dictionary

Comment: @Beatles1692, yes, Success is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your returning a dictionary. I assume the `EmployeeID` is unique so it can be simplified to:

```
var employees = new EmployeeInfoRepository()
  .GetEmployeesByDepartmentId(departmentId)
  .Select(e => new
  {
    ID = e.EmployeeID,
    Name = e.FullName
  }
return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in the script (success function)

```
$.each(response, function() {
  var option = $('<option></option>');
  option.val(response.ID);
  option.text(response.Name);
  $("#ddlEmployee").append(option);
});
```

Comment: "Success" function is called and an array of object is returned. However, the data is still not binding into "ddlEmployee".

Comment: Are you sure you have a `<select>` with `id="ddlEmployee"`?

Comment: Just tested it in my project with some dummy data - it works fine. There must be some other issue in your code - do you clear the existing options before calling the ajax method? (as in `$("#ddlEmployee").empty();)